# ip address of computer (history)

Tags: local-area-network

I was asked a question: how can you look for an ip address for the computer (XP,Vista) - this is no problem, but my question is how to get history of assigned IP's to computer - is it possible ?

Thanks!

//Vova

Answer (score 2):

This data is not persistently tracked in any real way. WMI can do quite a lot, especially if you're in a domain, and you can build a system that'll do this kind of tracking. But I don't know of a built in cache of such data within Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could search for the appropriate MAC address in the DHCP server logs, but not on the client.